# Network planning

Tags: wireless-networking

I would like to use a satellite internet, I would like to establish the following network topology.

[image]

I have a satellite internet, and I would like to share the internet through WiFi. I would like to use a switch which supports PoE because in this case I can supply the WiFi module through PoE. Is it enough a switch in the place of ??? or do I need a router?

Comment: What sort of environment is this to be in? Is this two homes or is it a business setup?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're saying. To distribute internet from a modem to multiple computers, I believe you'd need to use a router, and not just a switch, because you're connecting two different networks. Every computer would need its own IP address behind the router so that they can access the internet. If your WiFi module is a router, just connect it between the modem and the switch, with the modem going into its uplink port. You might even be able to use the router's extra LAN ports and do away with the switch entirely.

[image: It would look similar to this.]

Comment: Thank's for your answer, The distance between the two is 2km so I would like to use a switch which supports PoE, in this case I can supply the WiFi module.

Answer (score 0):

If the sites are close enough, I would recommend using a wireless router for both your wifi modems and switch.  I have something similar setup at home.  I have my modem going to a wireless router that connects to several PC's on the network.  Then I have another wireless router upstairs connecting several more PC's.  The 2 wireless routers form a wireless bridge.  It can be done with 2 routers that have DD-wrt firmware installed on them.

Comment: I need 2 wifi module because the distance between two is 1km.

Answer (score 0):

With a widely distributed network like this you'll need precisely aimed directional antennas between the two nodes of your network and a clear visual path between the antennas. Also, the wireless routers will need to be in "bridged" mode to act as pass-through devices.

The good news is, this setup isn't uncommon and there's plenty of hardware out there to do it.

Further, depending on how many hosts you'll be connected in the primary node, you may or may not be able to get rid of the switch. If there are only a few hosts, you'll be able to connect the hosts directly to the router, simplifying your topology.

Comment: I need the switch which is support PoE, in this case I can supply the WiFi module through PoE, and I also would like to connect a PoE IP camera.

Comment: PoE is easy enough to add.